# Does std::sort messes up with data in case of large data

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Run following code and you will see the data being messed up. I have a class with just integer inside it. Created a vector of 200 objects with 1 duplicate value. and used std::sort to sort those duplicate values only. Sort messes up my data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Test(const int x, int y = 0): x(x), y(y){}
    bool operator<(const Test& rhs)
    { return y < rhs.y; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Test> testVec;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 200; ++i)
    {
        testVec.emplace_back(Test(i, i/2));
    }
    testVec[99] = Test(101, 51);
    for(Test ele : testVec)
    { cout << "(" << ele.x << ", " << ele.y << ") "; }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    std::sort(testVec.begin(), testVec.end(), 
              [](const Test&a, const Test& b){
                  return a.x == b.x ? a.y > b.y : false;
              });
    for(Test ele : testVec)
    { cout << "(" << ele.x << ", " << ele.y << ") "; }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your comparater is not a strict weak ordering

Comment: I don't believe `return a.x == b.x ? true : false;` satisfies `std::sort`'s requirements for a comparison function.

Comment: Your ordering says "both `1 == 2` and `2 == 1` are false, so neither of 1 and 2 should be ordered before the other, but `1 == 1` is true, so 1 should be ordered before 1".

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare

Comment: On a side note, `a.x == b.x ? true : false` is usually written `a.x == b.x`.

Comment: And so you probably want `return a.x < b.x;`.

Comment: My actual use case is having some more conditions in comparator but it always returns true in one case only and in all other cases it returns false that is what i have written in snippet. So does the sort function messes the data if I give lot many NOs and very few YES for sorting somewhat big data?

Comment: Use case notwithstanding, if you're comparator is not weak order compliant, it cannot work, and is not supported by any/all standard algorithm that mandates as such (`std::sort` being the most obvious example). Invoking the mutable standard algorithms with non compliant ordering invokes *undefined behavior*. It *sounds* like what you're *really* trying to accomplish is a *priority queue* anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "sort these duplicate values"?

Comment: @Chetan The important point is not how many true or false cases you have, but what those cases are and how they are related. The requirements for a [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/strict_weak_order) are few and simple, but if you don't follow them you get undefined behaviour.